# Java playing mp3 and ogg

Tags: java, mp3, ogg

After countless hours of searching and reading through lots of source code I'm at a dead end and I'd need your help.
As the title suggests I'm trying to build (yet another) music player in Java. I stumbled upon the [Javazoom project](http://www.javazoom.net/projects.html) and it kinda works, but it also kinda doesn't. My goal is to be able to play mp3 and ogg files. Playing mp3s works without problems: I can get all information (ID3 tags and general audio file info) and I can perform all needed actions (play, pause, resume, seek, etc). But when I try to play ogg files I can get only one of the two, either I can play the file but get no file information or I get all information but can't play the file. My code is basically a revamped version of the BasicPlayer class, I tried looking through the jlGui player to see how it manages to be compatible with all formats but I'm just totally lost in that code.

[My MediaPlayer code](http://pastebin.com/i09VgECB)

Here's the command I use to compile the program:

```
javac -cp lib\jl1.0.1.jar;lib\jogg-0.0.7.jar;lib\jorbis-0.0.15.jar;liblog4j-1.2.16.jar;lib\mp3spi1.9.5.jar;lib\tritonus_share-0.3.6.jar;libvorbisspi1.0.3.jar MediaPlayer.java
```

When I execute it with

```
java -cp .;lib\jl1.0.1.jar;lib\jogg-0.0.7.jar;lib\jorbis-0.0.15.jar;liblog4j-1.2.16.jar;lib\mp3spi1.9.5.jar;libtritonus_jorbis-0.3.6.jar;libtritonus_share-0.3.6.jar;libvorbisspi1.0.3.jar MediaPlayer d:/foo.mp3
```

it displays the information and plays the file just fine, but when I try the same for d:/foo.ogg I get an exception:

```
167 [main] DEBUG MediaPlayer  - Target format: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing stream: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported conversion: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian from VORBISENC 48000.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, stereo, 1 bytes/frame, 16000.0 frames/second,
    at MediaPlayer.initAudioStream(MediaPlayer.java:302)
    at MediaPlayer.open(MediaPlayer.java:663)
    at MediaPlayer.main(MediaPlayer.java:772)
```

But when I then comment line 262 (the createLine() call in initAudioStream()) and run it with the same command it displays all file information but throws a similar exception

```
170 [main] DEBUG MediaPlayer  - Target format: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported conversion: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian from VORBISENC 48000.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, stereo, 1 bytes/frame, 16000.0 frames/second,
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at MediaPlayer.createLine(MediaPlayer.java:362)
    at MediaPlayer.initLine(MediaPlayer.java:392)
    at MediaPlayer.startPlayback(MediaPlayer.java:483)
    at MediaPlayer.play(MediaPlayer.java:672)
    at MediaPlayer.main(MediaPlayer.java:773)
```

AND when I then add the lib\tritonus_jorbis-0.3.6.jar to the classpath it plays the ogg file but displays no information.

So yeah... I'm pretty stumped and could really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the assumption that a player implementation will also provide metadata for the stream. Unfortunately, many implementations where never made with the goeal of providing metadata.

I would seperate retrieving metadata from playing, then you can use different libraries to access the metadata. You can then use a [library specialized in metadata manipluation](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) to solve this independently from playing the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try easyOgg:

http://cokeandcode.com/index.html?page=libs

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `javax.sound.sampled` implementation of jogg has a couple of shortcomings.
Perhaps you want to give [FFsampledSP](http://www.tagtraum.com/ffsampledsp/index.html) a shot. It's an FFmpeg based implementation for Win and OSX that also implements the `javax.sound.sampled` interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, using mp3spi 1.9.5-1 and vorbisspi 1.0.3-1. I had to put tritonus-share 0.3.7-2 and NOT 0.3.7-1 into the classpath, otherwise vorbisspi would not work.

I used Maven dependencies. The full working solution is here:
http://odoepner.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/play-mp3-or-ogg-using-javax-sound-sampled-mp3spi-vorbisspi/